# Angular HttpClient Post

Tags: angular, post, components, httpclient

I use a HttpClient in my service (MemberService) to use http.post. So i try to create a new user (addMember) in my website and add it in my database.

There is my MemberService :

```
export class MemberService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMembers(): Observable<IMember[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMember[]>('http://localhost:50867/api/Member');
  }

  getMember(memberId) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:50867/api/Member/' + memberId);
  }

  deleteMember(memberId) {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:50867/api/Member/' + memberId);
  }

  addMember(member: Object) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:50867/api/Member', member);
  }
}
```

I have create a form in my signUpComponent where can i recover the password, username, …

There is my signUpComponent :

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  private _pwd: string;
  private _cfPwd: string;
  private _btnEnable: boolean;
  private _email: string;
  private _username: string;
  public members = [];
  private  _newMember: Object;

  private emailPattern = '^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$';

  // btnEnable = false;

  private _isHiddenBothPassword = true;
  private _isHiddenEmail = true;

  constructor(public _memberService: MemberService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._btnEnable = false;
    this._isHiddenEmail = true;
    this._isHiddenBothPassword = true;

    this._memberService.getMembers()
      .subscribe(data => this.members = data);
  }

  public signUp() {
    console.log('ADD_MEMBER');
    console.log(this._email + this._username + this._pwd);
    this._newMember = [this._email, this._username, this._pwd, 0];
    this._memberService.addMember(this._memberService).subscribe();
  }
```

When i click on the button (in my html) that turn on my signUp() method. But it doesn't perform :/
There is my error :
[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIqsQ.png)

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is your `signUp` method:

```
  public signUp() {
    console.log('ADD_MEMBER');
    console.log(this._email + this._username + this._pwd);
    this._newMember = [this._email, this._username, this._pwd, 0];
    this._memberService.addMember(this._memberService).subscribe();
  }
```

See anything wrong?  I do.  You're passing `this._memberService` to `this._memberService.addMember` as if it were `this._newMember`.  Try calling that method with the correct variable and try again.

ie.  `this._memberService.addMember(this._newMember);`